# How to save text data the user enters in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I built an app that displays a list of goats with basic information such as name, age, breed and additional info (optional). The user can launch a dialog for each goat and enter text for the name, age, breed and additional info. Also can enter an image using coil library.

How can I save the data that the user enters for each goat so the next time the app is launched it displays?

I'm quite new to this and have no experience saving data.

Here is code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    //private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            GoatsTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {

                    GoatsApp(viewModel = MainViewModel())


                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }




@Composable
fun GoatsApp(viewModel: MainViewModel) {

    var goats: MutableList<Goats> = remember {
        mutableStateListOf(
            Goats(R.string.red, R.string.alpine, 7),
            Goats(R.string.little_goat, R.string.alpine, 8),
            Goats(R.string.nana, R.string.alpine, 7),
            Goats(R.string.sharkie, R.string.alpine, 10)
        )
    }

    var bucks: MutableList<Goats> = remember { mutableStateListOf(
        Goats(R.string.billy, R.string.mix, 7)
    ) }

    var isButtonClicked by mutableStateOf(false)

    val provider = GoogleFont.Provider(
        providerAuthority = "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
        providerPackage = "com.google.android.gms",
        certificates = R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs

    )
    val fontName = GoogleFont("Lato")

    val fontFamily = FontFamily(
        Font(googleFont = fontName, fontProvider = provider)
    )
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .padding(16.dp)
        .fillMaxHeight(0.90f)) {

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.95f)
                .border(3.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(13.dp))
        ) {
            Button(
                onClick = { goats.add(Goats(R.string.little_goat, R.string.alpine, 9)) },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                modifier = Modifier.background(Color.LightGray)
            ) {
                Text(text = "+")
            }
            Text(
                text = "Does",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(color = Color.LightGray)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(12.dp),
                fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraLight
            )


        }
        Row {
            GoatList(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp), goats = goats)
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.95f)
                .border(3.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(13.dp))
        ) {
            Button(
                onClick = { bucks.add(Goats(R.string.billy, R.string.mix, 9)) },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                modifier = Modifier.background(Color.LightGray)
            ) {
                Text(text = "+")
            }
            Text(
                text = "Bucks",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(color = Color.LightGray)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(12.dp),
                fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraLight
            )
        }

        BuckList(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp), bucks = bucks)
    }






}


@Composable
fun GoatCard(allGoats: Goats, viewModel: MainViewModel) {
//val years = allGoats.age.toString()


    var stateAdditional by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("Additional Text") }
    var stateName by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    var stateAge by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    val imageUri = rememberSaveable{ mutableStateOf("") }
    val myImage = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        imageUri.value.ifEmpty { R.drawable.pexels_anna_shvets_5953826}

    )
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) {
            uri: Uri? -> uri?.let {imageUri.value = it.toString()}
    }

    Card(modifier = Modifier) {
        Row{

            Image(painter = myImage, contentDescription = (stateName),
                modifier = Modifier.size(68.dp),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop)

            Column(Modifier.width(120.dp)) {

                Text(text = stateName, modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall)
                Row{
                    Text(text = stringResource(allGoats.breed), modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp), style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall)
                    Text(stateAge, modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp), style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall)

                    Box {
                        Button(onClick = { viewModel.isGoatClick() },
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.LightGray)) { }
                        Text(text = "More",
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall,
                            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(end = 6.dp, top = 12.dp))





                    }
                }

                if(viewModel.isDialogShown) {
                    CustomDialog(
                        onDismiss = { viewModel.onDismissDialog() },
                        myGoats = Goats(
                            name = allGoats.name,
                            age = allGoats.age,
                            breed = allGoats.breed
                        ),
                        onValueChange = { stateName = it },
                        value = stateName,
                        onAgeValueChange = { stateAge = it },
                        ageValue = stateAge,
                        launcher = launcher,
                        myImage = myImage,
                        addValue = stateAdditional,
                        addOnValueChange = { stateAdditional = it },

                        )
                }




            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun GoatList(modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
             goats: List<Goats>) {

    LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(1), modifier.padding(8.dp), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
        items(goats) { allGoats ->
            GoatCard(allGoats = allGoats, viewModel = MainViewModel())
        }

    }

}

@Composable
fun BuckList(modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
             bucks: List<Goats>) {

    LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(1), modifier.padding(8.dp), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
        items(bucks) { allGoats ->
            GoatCard(allGoats = allGoats, viewModel = MainViewModel())
        }

    }

}


@Composable
@Preview
fun previewApp() {
    GoatsApp(viewModel = MainViewModel())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to save data between app session you need to use persistent store.  In case with app settings is [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore). In case with user's data is database like [room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).

Answer (score 0):

Im using SharedPreference for save data

Try this:
Create a SharedPreferences Helper

```
class PreferencesHelper(context: Context) {
    private val preferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("goats_app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    fun saveGoatInfo(key: String, goatInfo: String) {
        preferences.edit().putString(key, goatInfo).apply()
    }

    fun getGoatInfo(key: String): String {
        return preferences.getString(key, "") ?: ""
    }
}
```

In your file GoatCad save the data or in other file

```
val preferencesHelper = PreferencesHelper(context = LocalContext.current)

preferencesHelper.saveGoatInfo("goat_$stateName", stateName)
preferencesHelper.saveGoatInfo("age_$stateName", stateAge)
```

For display data saved

```
val preferencesHelper = PreferencesHelper(context = LocalContext.current)

stateName = preferencesHelper.getGoatInfo("goat_$stateName")
stateAge = preferencesHelper.getGoatInfo("age_$stateName")
```

Comment: Where do I display the data?

Comment: Whit this code 
val preferencesHelper = PreferencesHelper(context = LocalContext.current)

stateName = preferencesHelper.getGoatInfo("goat_$stateName")
stateAge = preferencesHelper.getGoatInfo("age_$stateName")

Comment: It doesn't work. In what function do I display it?

Comment: I'm trying to call the last two pieces of code you gave me in the GoatCard function